# Array[RDD[(String, Set[String])]] transformation in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an Array of RDD of type Array[RDD[(String, Set[String])]], where each RDD is tuple of key and value.
Key is String and Value is Set[String], i want to merge/union Set's with same key. I am trying to do this in scala but no joy. Can you please help me out.

```
e.g.
RDD["A",Set("1","2")]
RDD["A",Set("3","4")]
RDD["B",Set("1","2")]
RDD["B",Set("3","4")]
RDD["C",Set("1","2")]
RDD["C",Set("3","4")]

After transformation:
RDD["A",Set("1","2","3","4")]
RDD["B",Set("1","2","3","4")]
RDD["C",Set("1","2","3","4")]
```

Comment: Does the result have to be an Array of RDD or a single RDD with those tuples?

Comment: Hi, it has to be a result of Array of RDD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a single `RDD` as output is ok (don't really see any reason to make many RDDs with only 1 record in them) you can reduce your `Array` of `RDD` into a single `RDD` and then do a `groupByKey`:

```
arr.reduce( _ ++ _ )
   .groupByKey
   .mapValues(_.flatMap(identity))
```

Exampe:

```
scala> val x = sc.parallelize( List( ("A", Set(1,2)) ) )
scala> val x2 = sc.parallelize( List( ("A", Set(3,4)) ) )
scala> val arr = Array(x,x2)
arr: Array[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int])]] = Array(ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:27, ParallelCollectionRDD[1] at parallelize at <console>:27)
scala> arr.reduce( _ ++ _ ).groupByKey.mapValues(_.flatMap(identity)).foreach(println)
(A,List(1, 2, 3, 4))
```

@Edit: I find it to be a really bad idea and would advice you to rethink it but you can get the result outut you want by getting all the keys from above and filtering the RDD multiple times:

```
val sub = arr.reduce( _ ++ _ ).groupByKey.mapValues(_.flatMap(identity))
val keys = sub.map(_._1).collect()
val result = for(k <- keys) yield sub.filter(_._1 == k)
result: Array[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Iterable[Int])]]
```

Each `RDD` will have a single tuple, don't really think it's very useful, performant.

Comment: @nilesh1212 well if you insist.. see my updated answer

Comment: Hi Mateus actually i need to write each rdd on HDFS with key as file name where each Set against the Key write a csv file.

Comment: @nilesh1212 ok, so what's the problem?

Comment: Nothing Mateus i was just answering your question on 'why array of rdd'

Comment: @nilesh1212 I see, so does my answer help you or are you still having some problems?